# Understanding PDFBox jar files

Tags: pdfbox

I am attempting to install PDFBox on my system in order to create PDF files, but am unsure which jar files I need. If I go to https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

I see command line tools as follows:

- pdfbox-app (9.1MB)
- preflight-app (9.2MB)
- debugger-app (9.0MB)

I also see "Libraries of each subproject" as follows:

- pdfbox (2.6MB)
- fontbox (1.6MB)
- preflight (248KB)
- xmpbox (132KB)
- pdfbox-tools (77KB)
- pdfbox-debugger (245KB)

What is meant by "each subproject"? Is it talking about the command line tools or something different?

I am planning to use java from the command line rather than in an IDE. Does this mean that I just need the Command line tools or do I need the "Libraries of each Subproject" as well? What does the "-app" indicated in the command line tools vs the related libraries?

Is there a page on apache.org that mentions the differences between all of these?

To create PDF files should I be using the preflight and debugger files as well or are those optional?

Comment: When you write "I am planning to use java from the command line rather than in an IDE" do you mean you want to use the command line tools ( https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html ) or does it mean you want to code in java but avoid IDEs, because you're uncomfortable in having a life that is too easy so you use `javac` directly and also insist on driving a stick shift car? For the command line tools you need pdfbox-app, this contains everything (except libraries with the "wrong license", e.g. jai_imageio.jar).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am using a remote web server in which I am connecting to via SSH. I will be coding in java and using javac to compile the application. I will likely be using vim as my editor rather than sticking with ed.

Comment: With the link you provided and because I am creating a Java program that links to PDFBox I am thinking I do not need the command line tools.

Comment: You could use the pdfbox-app jar, but this would be too big (but easy), so to create PDF files you'll just need pdfbox and fontbox and commons-log. If you want to do advanced stuff, e.g. read / render / decrypt / sign PDF files, then read pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html too.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. One last point of clarification: You said to create PDF files then all I need is pdfbox/fontbox/commons-log, but to do things like rendering I need additional dependencies. What is the difference between creating a PDF file and rendering a PDF file?

Comment: rendering means convert to image. "create a PDF" means just that, creating from text that you position, or draw lines, or put external images.

Comment: Great, thank you that has helped a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments: you want to create a PDF from scratch and access your development over `ssh` so you can't use an IDE and have to use `javac`. For that you could use pdfbox-app jar file, but this would be huge. Instead, use the pdfbox, fontbox and commons-log jar files. See also [here](http://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html) for additional dependencies if you want to do more advanced stuff (read / render (= convert to image) / decrypt / sign).